# Error when checking target: expected activation_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (70612, 1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I Keep getting the error: Error when checking target: expected activation_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (70612, 1). What could be the issue?

see below code:

```
# CNN Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(256, 8))

model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (2)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size =(2)))


model.add(Dense(64)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer ="adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])

**Model Summary:**

Model: "sequential_37"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_37 (Embedding)     (None, None, 8)           2048      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_47 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 32)          800       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_43 (MaxPooling (None, None, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_48 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 32)          3104      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_44 (MaxPooling (None, None, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, None, 64)          2112      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_18 (Dropout)         (None, None, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_35 (Dense)             (None, None, 2)           130       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)   (None, None, 2)           0         
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last layer has 3 dimension, it should have been 2 `(batch, n_class)`.

`activation_12 (Activation)   (None, None, 2)           0`

You need to add a `Flatten()` layer before

`model.add(Dense(64)`

Another issue is you have your labels with shape `(batch, 1)`.

You need to use `sigmoid` instead of `softmax` (assuming binary classification).

Also, change the shape of x and y.

`x = x.reshape((-1, 533, 1))`
`y = y.reshape(-1,1)`

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(256, 8, input_length = 533))

model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (2)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size =(2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1)) # 1
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer ="adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

Comment: Thanks quite new to deep learning. Yes it is binary classification. I have implemented the corrections and I am getting this value error: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, 32)). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.

Comment: In your embedding layer, `model.add(Embedding(256, 8))` specify the input_shape.

Comment: The value error changes to ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_49 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)

Comment: what's your x and y shapes?

Comment: The error is: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_13 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (68926, 2). My X.shape is (86158, 533) and my Y shape is (86158,)

Comment: Check the updated answer, the error should go away.